# jQuery selector differences after page refresh

Tags: jquery

When the page is first loaded the snippet below alerts the correct value. If I F5 the page however I get an alert of the first option in the select, which is not the correct value. If I put the cursor in the URL bar and hit Enter then I again get the correct value.

This snippet comes out of the [idealforms.js](http://code.google.com/p/idealforms/) file which isn't working properly and I'm trying to correct it. It's possible that this issue influenced from somewhere else in the code but I have my doubts.

Any idea why this is happening, does a page refresh somehow behave differently then when the page is first loaded?

```
form.find('select').each(function () {          
    var select = $(this);                                               
    nu_title = select.find(':selected').html();
    alert(nu_title);
});
```

Comment: You have an extra `}`on the end of your code, is that a typo or is it in the real code?

Comment: What browser are you using? With Firefox, form fields remember the value you entered even on a refresh of the page so you can get unexpected results. You have to navigate to the page again to have a real "refresh" of form fields.

Comment: @bfavaretto it's a typo, omitted now

Answer (score 0):

On some browsers after `F5`, values filled in forms stay. `CTRL+F5` (or re-entering the page from the url bar, like you suggested) should clear those under most settings.